# Radio button not being checked based on ReactJS state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, this should have been easy! But the title mentions when I click on the radio button they either don't get checked or they get checked at the wrong time.

Here a link to the live version of the code https://codesandbox.io/s/0wr7L3K5

Here is my `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Radio from './Radio';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Radio voteName="yes" label="Yes" />
    <Radio voteName="no" label="No" />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is `Radio.js`

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class VoteItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedVote: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const newVal = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      selectedVote: newVal,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="input">
        <input
          id={this.props.voteName}
          type="radio"
          value={this.props.voteName}
          name="voteval"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          checked={this.state.selectedVote === this.props.voteName}
        />
        {this.props.label}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have seen most of SO question all most all of them suggest removing `event.preventDefault()` to render the check, but as you can see I don't have that.

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem. You could simply give a name to the input so that one value gets checked and it gets updated through handleChange. https://codesandbox.io/s/RoKjBLJ5V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your selected state to Radio.js 's superview.
Such as:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1rXWKZLo0

Comment: So this is the answer, the explanation on why I need to do this is when the state changes it only changes for the single Radio, therefore the second one will not re render! If I move up the state into a parent the change will propagate down and cause both of them to re render.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Radio Button Group component.

This one have a state containing the selected voteName.

Radio's onChange function invoke a method of this Radio Button Group Component, then it re-render child.